# Get list of files where date older than 7 days?

Tags: bash, date, ubuntu, pattern-matching

I have a script that creates mysql backups, the files end up being called.

`DB_name-M_D_Y.gz` so for example `stackoverflow_users-04_10_2013.gz`

Now I don't know the name of the files before hand, just the pattern.

What I need to do is adapt the script to, before it creates new backups, check if the date in any of the files is older that 7 days, if so do other things with those.

I know how to do the other things, but getting the list of files in the first place is the difficult one.

I cannot just use the modified date as the files get touched by other scripts so need to read the date from the file name.

So, How can I get a list of the files?

---

For replying to comments assume this dummy data

Current Date: 10<sup>th</sup> April 2013

```
database zero-03_31_2013.gz    #Older | Notice this one has spaces
database_one-04_01_2013.gz     #Older
database_two-04_02_2013.gz     #Older
database_three-04_03_2013.gz   #Newer | Actually 7 days, but we want OLDER than!
database_four-04_04_2013.gz    #Newer
database_five-04_05_2013.gz    #Newer
dater.sh                       #Does not have the .gz extension | Not deleted
```

Bash Version

```
matthew@play:~/test$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: First thing I'd do is to make the date format YYYY-MM-DD so filenames become sortable...

Comment: That's the first thing I would do too, if I was allowed :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# get the date 7 days ago
sevenDaysAgo=$(date -d "-7 day 00:00:00" +%s)

# create an array to hold the files older than 7 days
result=()

# loop over the files
while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r file
do
    # extract the date from each filename using a regex
    if [[ $file =~ ^.*-([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+).gz$ ]]
    then
        m="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        d="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        y="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
        fileDateTime="$(date -d ${y}${m}${d} +%s)"

        # check if the date is older than 7 days ago
        if (( fileDateTime < sevenDaysAgo ))
        then
            result+=( "$file" )
        fi
    fi
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.gz" -print0)

# print out the results for testing
for f in "${result[@]}"
do
    echo "$f"
done
```

Comment: Fantastic, it works well, now the last question is, is there any way to make the script assume that all the database files were created in the last second of the day they were created (e.g. if the date is 03_31_2013 make it be interpreted as 03_31_2013_23_59_59)?

Comment: As the present output is ./database_two-04_02_2013.gz ./database_four-04_04_2013.gz ./database_one-04_01_2013.gz ./database_three-04_03_2013.gz ./database zero-03_31_2013.gz and with the date being the 10th of April the ones dated 04_03_2013 and 04_04_2013 should not be in that list!

Comment: To assume that files were created at 23:59:59 change it to: `fileDateTime=$(date -d "${y}${m}${d} 23:59:59" +%s)`

Comment: @dogbane: Or maybe truncate hours, minutes and seconds when you assign `sevenDaysAgo`

Comment: yep, was just about to say that: `sevenDaysAgo=$(date -d "-7 day 00:00:00" +%s)`

Comment: Ah awesome, that works, I had just done `fileDateTime=$(($(date -d ${y}${m}${d} +%s)+86399))` but that works better, also `fileDateTime` needs a $ sign when you are doing the comparison I think?

Comment: it's ok not to have a dollar sign on variables within an `(( arithmetic expression ))`. To be consistent, I have removed the other dollar too.